# Special character "dot over dash"

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I need the symbol "dot over dash" or "dot over minus", but I am unable to find it [in a list of LaTeX symbols](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/Symbols.pdf). When composing it via `\dot{-}`, the dot is so hight, that it looks weired. It should look like this:

[image]

Did I overlook the symbol in the list or how can I compose it?

Comment: have you looked for it in [this](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) list?

Comment: I can’t post this as an answer, but an alternative to morbusg’s/egreg’s solution which does not need arbitrary shifts, and also uses a less heavy dot (which I find more pleasing to the eye) is `\mathbin{\scriptstyle\dot{\smash{\textstyle-}}}`. One can define a macro working also in sub/superscripts with `\newcommand\dotminus{\mathbin{\mathchoice{\scriptstyle\dodotminus\displaystyle}{\scriptstyle\dodotminus\textstyle}{\scriptscriptstyle\dodotminus\scriptstyle}{\scriptscriptstyle\dodotminus\scriptscriptstyle}}} \newcommand\dodotminus[1]{\dot{\smash{#1-}}}`.

Comment: I also observe that while plain `\mathbin{\dot-}` looks awful in LaTeX, it works just perfect in Mathjax, strangely enough.

Comment: @ManuelFaux Could you help to comment how to input the symbol "dot over dash" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Comprehensive List of LateX symbols](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive) (a very useful guide, by the way), the `\dotdiv` command (part of the `mathabx` package) produces the desired operator.

Comment: many of the symbols in `mathabx` have different shapes than those in computer modern.  what's probably best here is to load just the particular symbol(s) needed.  see [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/579) for the method.

Comment: @ach Could you help to comment how to input the symbol "dot over dash" ?

Answer (score 15):

A variation of morbusg solution that works also for subscripts and superscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\dotminus}{\mathbin{\text{\@dotminus}}}

\newcommand{\@dotminus}{%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth\raise1ex\hbox{.}\hidewidth\cr$\m@th-$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$a\dotminus b_{c\dotminus d}$ \fbox{$\dotminus$}

$a-b_{c-d}$ \fbox{$-$}
\end{document}
```

The formulas are repeated with `-` to see that the space occupied is the same.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's a try at building one:

```
\def\dotminus{\mathbin{\ooalign{\hss\raise1ex\hbox{.}\hss\cr
  \mathsurround=0pt$-$}}}

$ a \dotminus b $
\bye
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The official unicode name is [`dot minus`](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2200.pdf), and among the packages that have it is `mnsymbol`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mnsymbol,lmodern}

\begin{document}
$a \dotminus b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That solution works, but the `mnsymbol` package changes my other symbols (e.g. the equals sign gets narrower).

Comment: The issue is that `mnsymbol` (unlike, say, `amssymb`) is not just a motley collection of supplementary symbols for Computer Modern: it’s a mathematics support package for documents using [Adobe Minion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Minion), and should therefore not be used unless the text font is also changed.

Answer (score 3):

If using [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) is an option, you could input it directly

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
    $A ∸ B = θ$
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]